# Matching specific characters in FLEX/LEX

Tags: lex

Say for example I have strings like

The Undiscovered Country

Return of the Jedi

The Motion Picture

The Phantom Menace

Attack of the Clones

And I only want it to return the ones starting with "The" how do I match the first 3 characters specifically in a line?

Answer (score 0):

You can match text starting only at the beginning of a line by putting a `^` at the beginning of the pattern. (The beginning of a line is either the beginning of the input, or the character immediately following a newline (`\n`) character.)

So the following will categorize lines into whole lines starting with `The` and all other whole lines:

```
^"The ".*    { /* yytext is a line starting with The, not including the newline. */ }
.+         { /* yytext is a line not starting with The. */ }
\n         ; /* Ignore newline characters */
```

Note: The pattern only matches lines which start with `The` (including the space). That's not the same as lines starting `The` (which would include `These errors`), and nor is it the same as lines starting with the *word* `The` (which might include something like `The--only--way forward`). In general, getting a lexical specification right means thinking carefully about all the corner cases, and deciding for each one what the desired outcome is.